# Help identifying Cumulative Expectation vs. Cumulative Identification Graph

Tags: classification, data-visualization, roc

In a classification problem, I rank scored observations descending by (calibrated) probability of positive result.  If I create a graph that shows cumulative % of total expectation captured on the Y-axis, and cumulative % of units marked positive on the X-axis, what kind of graph is this?  Does it have a name?

(Seems similar to an ROC curve, but I don't think they're the same)

[image: graph of cumulative expectation vs cumulative identification]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a reframing of the "Cumulative Gains Chart", as discussed [here](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/%7Edbd/cs831/notes/lift_chart/lift_chart.html).